# How do I do a rampage?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've seen a couple of messages like:

> Hero1 is on rampage.

How do they do it?

Comment: downvote for being a noob?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a champion manages to get multiple kills without dying, they go on a killing spree, which increases the amount of gold you get for killing them. The announcement for the killing spree changes based on how many kills in a row they've achieved, going from "Champion is on a killing spree!" at three kills up to "Champion is legendary!" at eight or more kills.

To answer your specific question, a rampage is announced when a champion kills four champions without dying.

For the full list of killing spree announcement names and bounty rewards, visit [LoLWiki's page on Kills](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kill#Gold_reward).

Answer (score 0):

its a killing streak: Killing enemies without dying. Rampage is 4 I think.